# Resize image on Hugo site generated with Blogdown

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I am trying to resize an image on a Hugo site generated with [Blogdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/).

In particular, I'm looking to add an image which is in a folder in the `static/_media/` directory.

E.g., on [a page on my Hugo site](https://jrosen48.github.io/teaching/), I added the following two lines to the top of the `.md` file:

```
![test image](/_media/logos/pdf_100100.png)

![test image 2](/_media/logos/pdf.png)
```

The first is resized to have dimensions of 100 x 100 pixels, while the second is 720 x 720. However, they both render the same size. How can I resize an image - either outside or inside of Blogdown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize image in Hugo (v 0.32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063067/resize-image-in-hugo-v-0-32)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think resizing a blogdown image is possible (without using a shortcode).

You might want to look at this answer: [Resize image in Hugo (v 0.32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063067/resize-image-in-hugo-v-0-32)