# Image Processing Outside Bundles

Tags: hugo

Is it possible to use Hugo 0.32's new image processing feature for images in other folders?

For example, I have a site that is already structured in a format with all media in a separate `/content/images` folder, instead of beside each entry as a page bundle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to access resources of a page from it's reference, so this is possible with a pretty simple setup.

Create an `_index.md` file in the `content/images` folder with simple front-matter similar to below.

`content/images/_index.md`

```md
---
title: Media Folder
---
```

This will allow you to access the resources for `images` within the section from the site context and get the page. If you don't want this to show up as an actual page on your published website, you can add `headless: true`.

### Listing the images from another Page Template

```html
{{ with .Site.GetPage "section" "images" }}
  <h2>{{ .Title }}</h2>
  {{ $resources := .Resources.ByType "image"}}
  {{ range $resources }}
    {{ with . }}
      <img style="max-width: 100%;" src="{{ .RelPermalink }}">
      <br />
    {{ end }}
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

### Listing and resizing the resource images

```html
{{ with .Site.GetPage "section" "images" }}
  <h2>From {{ .Title }} (images)</h2>
  {{ $resources := .Resources.ByType "image"}}
  {{ range $resources }}
    {{ with . }}
      {{ $image200x := (.Resize "200x") }}
      {{ $image400x := (.Resize "400x") }}
      <img src="{{ $image200x.RelPermalink }}">
      <img src="{{ $image400x.RelPermalink }}">
      <br />
    {{ end }}
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

These were examples to show how to access the resources from within the `images` location from another location in the bundle. You can also access the individual image by name by using `.Resources.GetByPrefix "logo"` to get the image resource directly.

### Access an Image resource by name

In the front matter of the page you would include a field `imagename: logo` as an example, then:

```html
{{ $page := . }}
{{ with .Site.GetPage "section" "images" }}
  {{ with .Resources.GetByPrefix $page.Params.imagename }}
    {{ $image200x := (.Resize "200x") }}
    {{ $image400x := (.Resize "400x") }}
    <img src="{{ $image200x.RelPermalink }}">
    <img src="{{ $image400x.RelPermalink }}">
    <br />
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

**NOTE:** You could also access these images from the markdown, but that will require a shortcode setup like in the `Hugo` docs and I have included examples of a shortcode in the GitHub example link below.

[Here is the GitHub repository of the example](https://github.com/talves/hugo-resource-images)

Comment: I will soon add a link to the GitHub repo to show a working example.